# RED5 RTMPConnManager does not set the applicationContext local variable. This causes a NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, netbeans-7, red5

I compiled the latest RED5 sources (client, server, and io) on Netbeans. I want to start my AXIS camera capturer and streamer appplication, but a NullPointerException happens. I think that some Spring configuration files are missing. If you have any idea, please help me!

Here is the error:

```
10:49:39.882 [main] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Set handler: org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPClient@167416eb
10:49:39.886 [main] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - setExceptionHandler: null
10:49:39.890 [main] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - connect server: 127.0.0.1 port 1935 connect - params: {objectEncoding=0, app=live, flashVer=WIN 11,2,202,235, fpad=false, tcUrl=rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live, audioCodecs=3575, videoFunction=1, pageUrl=null, path=live, capabilities=15, swfUrl=null, videoCodecs=252} callback: hu.arh.capturepublish.CapturerPublisher@3a962da5 args: null
10:49:39.890 [main] INFO  o.r.c.net.rtmp.BaseRTMPClientHandler - rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live
10:49:39.947 [NioProcessor-2] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Session created
10:49:39.983 [NioProcessor-2] WARN  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Exception creating connection
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnectionInstance(RTMPConnManager.java:284) [classes/:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnection(RTMPConnManager.java:144) [classes/:na]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnection(RTMPConnManager.java:55) [classes/:na]
    at org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.createRTMPMinaConnection(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:228) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.sessionCreated(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:82) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:642) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:372) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$700(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:762) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.sessionCreated(IoFilterAdapter.java:74) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:372) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:365) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.service.IoServiceListenerSupport.fireSessionCreated(IoServiceListenerSupport.java:211) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.addNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:534) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.handleNewSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:501) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1105) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
10:49:39.984 [NioProcessor-2] WARN  o.r.c.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Exception caught null
10:49:39.985 [NioProcessor-2] ERROR o.r.c.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Exception detail
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.sessionCreated(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:84) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:642) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:372) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$700(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:762) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.sessionCreated(IoFilterAdapter.java:74) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:372) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:365) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.service.IoServiceListenerSupport.fireSessionCreated(IoServiceListenerSupport.java:211) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.addNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:534) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.handleNewSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:501) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1105) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
10:49:39.985 [NioProcessor-2] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Session opened
10:49:39.985 [NioProcessor-2] DEBUG o.r.c.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Handshake - client phase 1
10:49:39.986 [NioProcessor-2] WARN  o.r.c.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Exception caught null
10:49:39.986 [NioProcessor-2] ERROR o.r.c.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler - Exception detail
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.red5.client.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.sessionOpened(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:115) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.sessionOpened(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:655) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionOpened(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:386) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$800(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.sessionOpened(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:767) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.sessionOpened(IoFilterAdapter.java:81) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionOpened(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:386) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$800(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.sessionOpened(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:767) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.sessionOpened(IoFilterAdapter.java:81) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionOpened(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:386) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$800(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:47) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.sessionOpened(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:767) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.sessionOpened(IoFilterAdapter.java:81) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionOpened(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:386) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireSessionOpened(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:379) [mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.service.IoServiceListenerSupport.fireSessionCreated(IoServiceListenerSupport.java:212) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.addNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:534) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.handleNewSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:501) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:67) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1105) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) ~[mina-core-2.0.8-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real sure what to make of the log data, but to make sure you get the application context injected you'll have to ensure that you implement the ApplicationContextAware class and make an entry for your implementing class in the red5-web.xml or whichever Spring app context xml you are using in the server.